# ¿Porque los registros en una tabla de Postgresql, guarda espacios en blanco?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

Quetal amigos, estoy haciendo una practica con usando PHP + PDO y postgresql, y me he dado cuenta que al guardar los datos este me deja espacios en blanco.

Les adjunto una imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el codigo.

```
<?php 
    include_once "conexion.php";
    try {  

      $pdo->beginTransaction();

      $result = $pdo->exec("insert into company (name, age, address, salary ) values (  'Juan Leo', '1','xxx','23.2')");


      if($result > 0){
        echo "Datos agregados! :)";
      }else{
        echo "No se agrego nada! :C";
      }

      $pdo->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $pdo->rollBack();
      echo "Fallo: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

 ?>
```

y al parecer en el campo name, este lo guarda sin los espacios. al parecer solo en los campos de tipo **character**
alguna sugerencia, para que no pase esto?
gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a completar con algo sobre la documentación de PostgreSQL, y de paso lo tenemos como fuente en castellano.

En resumen, se puede decir que PostrgreSQL tiene tres tipos de datos para caracteres:

- `character varying` : tamaño variable con límite, se puede usar `varchar` como alias
- `character` : tamaño fijo, rellena en blanco los espacios vacíos, se puede usar `char` como alias.
- `text` : tamaño variable ilimitado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-TABLE) dice algunas cosas interesantes sobre cómo funciona cada uno de estos tipos de datos y qué ventajas/desventajas tendría usar uno u otro.

Aquí la traducción textual:

> SQL define dos tipos de caracteres principales: `character varying
>   (n)` y `character (n)`, donde `n` es un número entero positivo. Ambos
>   tipos pueden almacenar cadenas de hasta `n` caracteres (no bytes) de
>   longitud. Un intento de almacenar una cadena más larga en una columna
>   de estos tipos dará como resultado un error, a menos que los
>   caracteres en exceso sean todos espacios, en cuyo caso la cadena se
>   truncará a la longitud máxima. (Esta excepción algo extraña es
>   requerida por el estándar SQL). **Si la cadena que se va a almacenar
>   es más corta que la longitud declarada, los valores de tipo carácter
>   serán espaciados; los valores de caracteres de tipo variable
>   simplemente almacenarán la cadena más corta.**
>
> Si uno convierte explícitamente un valor a `character varying(n)` o
>   `character(n)`, entonces un valor de longitud excesiva se truncará en
>   n caracteres sin generar un error. (Esto también es requerido por el
>   estándar SQL).
>
> Las notaciones `varchar (n)` y `char (n)` son alias para `character
>   varying(n)` y `character(n)`, respectivamente. `character` sin
>   especificador de longitud es equivalente a `character (1)`. Si se
>   utiliza  `character varying` sin el especificador de longitud, el tipo
>   acepta cadenas de cualquier tamaño. Esta última es una extensión de
>   PostgreSQL.
>
> Además, PostgreSQL proporciona el tipo **`text`**, que almacena
>   cadenas de cualquier longitud. Aunque el tipo `text` no está en el
>   estándar SQL, también lo tienen otros sistemas de administración de
>   bases de datos SQL.
>
> Los valores de tipo `character` están rellenos físicamente con
>   espacios con el ancho `n` especificado, y se almacenan y se muestran
>   de esa manera. Sin embargo, los espacios de relleno se tratan como
>   semánticamente insignificantes. Los espacios finales no se tienen en
>   cuenta al comparar dos valores de tipo `character`, y se eliminarán al
>   convertir un valor de `character` a uno de los otros tipos de cadena.
>   Tenga en cuenta que los espacios finales son semánticamente
>   significativos en los valores de tipo `character varying` y en los
>   valores de `text`, y cuando se usa la coincidencia de patrones, por
>   ejemplo `LIKE`, expresiones regulares, etc.
>
> El requisito de almacenamiento para una cadena corta (hasta 126 bytes)
>   es de 1 byte más la cadena real, que incluye el relleno de espacio en
>   el caso de `character`. Las cadenas más largas tienen 4 bytes de
>   sobrecarga en lugar de 1. Las cadenas largas son comprimidas por el
>   sistema automáticamente, por lo que el requisito físico en el disco
>   puede ser menor. Los valores muy largos también se almacenan en tablas
>   de fondo para que no interfieran con el acceso rápido a valores de
>   columna más cortos. En cualquier caso, la cadena de caracteres más
>   larga posible que se puede almacenar es de aproximadamente 1 GB. (El
>   valor máximo que se permitirá para `n` en la declaración del tipo de
>   datos es menor que eso. No sería útil cambiar esto porque con las
>   codificaciones de caracteres multibyte el número de caracteres y bytes
>   puede ser bastante diferente. Si desea almacenar cadenas largas sin
>   límite superior específico, use `text` o `character varying` sin un
>   especificador de longitud, en lugar de compensar un límite de longitud
>   arbitrario).
>
> **Consejo**: No existe diferencia de rendimiento entre estos tres tipos, aparte de un mayor espacio de almacenamiento cuando se usa el
>   tipo de relleno en blanco, y algunos ciclos de CPU adicionales para
>   verificar la longitud cuando se almacena en una columna de longitud
>   limitada. Si bien el `character (n)` tiene ventajas de rendimiento en
>   algunos otros sistemas de bases de datos, no existe tal ventaja en
>   PostgreSQL; de hecho, el **`character (n)` suele ser el más lento de
>   los tres debido a sus costos adicionales de almacenamiento**. En la
>   mayoría de las situaciones, se debe usar `text` o `character varying`
>   en su lugar.

Answer (score 1):

No conozco postgresql pero he visto algo parecido en otras implementaciones de SQL. Es por usar el tipo `character` que te va a rellenar con espacios hasta alcanzar los 50 caracteres que has definido.

Utiliza otro tipo con longitud variable, en mysql tenemos `varchar`, por ejemplo.

Comment: ok, es lo que supuse, de todas maneras ya lo pude arreglar utilizando otro tipo, **charater varying**.