# current_timestamp no existe en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una base de datos que esta sobre Heroku. Un campo se llena automáticamente con la fecha. Intento usar `current_timestamp`, pero parece que no funciona.

Aquí está el esquema de la base de datos.

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar,
  email varchar,
  username varchar,
  password varchar,
  register_date CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() not null
);
```

Aquí está la consulta:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, username, password) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, email, username, password))
```

Y aquí está el error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
LINE 7:   register_date CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() not null
```

Comment: El `not null` sobra y el tipo de dato falta. Prueba así: **`register_date   timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp`**  ... bueno puedes dejar el `not null` en efecto, para evitar que posteriormente sea seteado a  nulo:  **`register_date   timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp`**

Comment: @A.Cedano, gracias parece que la ultima consulta funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`** sí existe en PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), lo que hay en tu consulta es un error de sintaxis debido a que:

- **no estás especificando el tipo de dato de la columna `register_date`**
- estás escribiendo `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` con paréntesis
- no estás usando `DEFAULT`
- no estás creando bien la primary key

Si escribes la consulta así, el error debería desaparecer:

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users (
  id             bigserial       primary key,
  name           varchar (150),
  email          varchar (150),
  username       varchar (50),
  password       varchar (50),
  register_date  timestamp       default current_timestamp not null
);
```

**Otra cosa:** Conviene que a las columnas `varchar` les indiques un tamaño, sino las creará como si fueran `text`, lo cual no es bueno. [Puedes leer esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/177015/29967), en la que he traducido de la documentación cómo funcionan las columnas `varchar` cuando no se especifica un tamaño en ellas.

Comment: Gracias padre, intenté la respuesta pero me da la misma error

Answer (score 1):

Como lo indica es un error de sintaxis en el tipo de dato **register_date** y en el **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()**  quita los paréntesis `()`   y falta agregar **DEFAULT** antes del **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** de la siguiente forma:

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar,
  email varchar,
  username varchar,
  password varchar,
  register_date timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null
);
```